# html comment with conditional expression

Tags: html

In foundation css they use this at top of html doc as last in a series of conditional browser checks.

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

When IE version is greater than IE 8, what is the equivalent expression?

```
<!--> <html lang="en"> <!-- ?????
```

I take it `<!-->` is legal syntax for an empty comment?

The `<!--<![endif]-->` block is confusing me.

Is the endif evaluated even though it appears to be nested inside a comment?

Isn't the `<![endif]` always commented out regardless of IE version? Or does IE still evaluate this even though it appears to be inside html comment?

I guess I need some help figuring out how this is parsed and how start/end tags are matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code will be f.e executed only in internet explorer no matter it looks like a comment:

```
<!--[if IE]><!-->
function onlyIE(){
    some code...
}
<!--<![endif]-->
```

You can find more info on this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: Thanks, that link helps.  I guess I'm used to always seeing balancing ending '>' for each and every every '<'.